# java lambda foreach update value non final variable

Tags: java

I want to update the amount value, but it need to be final

```
int amount = 0;

// update value somewhere
amount = 12;

txs.forEach(p -> {
    p.setAmount(amount);
});
```

How to update all the txs with the same value?

Comment: Put it into the effectively final variable.

Comment: does this compile?? ***int amount 0;***

Comment: Do you need the amount variable to be final? If no then explain a bit more. When a final variable is declared and assigned its value cannot be changed. So first declare the variable as final int amount;  and do not assign any value. Assign at a place where you need. Or declare and assign at class level as a static constant. It all depends on your requirement.

Comment: You need to provide more context. You could simply write `int amount = 12` in the first place, but I think you are already aware of that. So you need to show us where and how exactly you are planning to update the `amount` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do it: Create a temporary variable like that:

```java
int amount = 0;

// update value somewhere
amount = 12;

final int myFinalVariable = amount;

txs.forEach(p -> p.setAmount(myFinalVariable));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can  do it like this

```
int amount = 0;

// update value somewhere
amount = 12;

  // add this
final int final_amount = amount ;

txs.forEach(p -> {
    p.setAmount(final_amount);
});
```